# sending information over 2 computers on the same network

Tags: apache, communication, form-submit

I'm developing a web based application which will gather user choices from a menu, and once the user presses submit, it will send over the form to a computer over the same network. I have looked into sockets to figure out how it would work.

Comment: Can you tell a little bit more about what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean to a php page hosted on some other computer...

If so you could use CURL to push it to the other page.

Comment: hey brian thanks for the response, basically the user goes through a list of options, selects which one they want. once thats done, it would be transferred to a computer which would simply read the order they have made. i have just visited the cURL page, but i didnt make much sense of how it would be implemented within a php page to transfer the request the user has made to the other computer. would a php front end and an SQL back end make sense, where the other host could access the backend to view the order? sorry if it makes little sense